# center form and div horizontally and vertically using pure javascript or pure css

Tags: javascript, html, css, centering

I have a `web form` with a `div` container called `"content"` that contains a `web form`, I'd like to have this container `centered` both `vertically` and `horizontally` but I cannot obtain this effect, I'm looking for a `javascript` or pure `css` solution.

example.html

```
<html>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="content">
<form action="..." name="...">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

example.css

```
#content {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, FreeSans, 'Nimbus Sans L', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  color: #E6E6FA;
  background-color: #191D26;
  background-image: url("bkg-3.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border: #E6E6FA 1px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 430px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I tried also using pure css solution as below:

```
#content {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

but under IE 9.0 I see a strange behavior... any method (`javascript` or pure `css`) is welcome and any ideas is appreciated.

[image: example]

Comment: but you have it in center yet or not?

Comment: is a fake because using <br> and margin: 0 auto I simulated a centered div but is a fake... a trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some `css` and `javascript` solutions.

**html:**

```
<div class="content">
  etcetera...
  etcetera...
  etcetera...
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.content {
  width: 430px;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
  var div_width = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].offsetWidth;
  var div_height = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].offsetHeight;
  var set_width = div_width/2;
  var set_height = div_height/2;
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.height = div_height+'px';
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.width = div_width+'px';
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.position = 'absolute';
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.top = '50%'
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.left = '50%';
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.marginLeft = -set_width+'px';
  document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].style.marginTop = -set_height+'px';
}
</script>
```

Finally this works for me and the `div` is `centered` automatically in `horizontal` and `vertical` as I wanted... thanks.

Comment: I have only a consideration about my code, won't work on internet explorer 7/8 while work on internet explorer 9 or above, if applied to very big page may take some seconds to render the position the div... for the rest is ok!

Answer (score 2):

With this CSS you can center it horizontally and vertically, supported in all browsers. Only bad thing about it is that you require fixed width and height, ofcourse you can format this to javascript and get the height and width of the element, but the trick is the same:

```
#form {
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-400px; /*half of the height*/
    margin-left:-250px; /*half of the width*/
}
```

---

Assuming you have a variable height, you will have to use JavaScript:

```
var elemStyle = document.getElementById("yourDivId").style;
elemStyle.marginTop = elemStyle.height / 2
```

Note: javascript above is just a sample and might not work directly, but it gives you an idea on how to implement it.

Comment: note that height is auto since I have no height in my css because the div is generated by php and the width may be changed by php... so I cannot use fixed positions in the css otherwise I did it at beginning of my project... but thanks.

Comment: As I said you can retreive the height with javascript, and then just apply it to the CSS (after dividing it by 2 ofcourse). I have editted my answer to help you out a bit.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function CenterDiv() {
    var elemStyle = document.getElementById("content").style;
    elemStyle.marginTop = elemStyle.height / 2;
  }
  </script> and onload="CenterDiv();" with .content {margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; } and adding to div "content" the id="content"...

Answer (score 2):

For placing div in middle of horizontal give some width to the div, and margin-left, margin-right as auto

```
#mydiv{
  width:200px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
```

for making vertical in js,

```
 var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
   // alert(y); //window height
    elm = document.getElementById('mydiv')
    elm.style.marginTop = (parseInt(y)-elm.clientHeight)/2 +"px"
```

Comment: it was my mistake.. I accidentally put clientHeight as height. Now its working.

Comment: Date & Time: 21/05/2014 16.49.25
Error: TypeError: elm is null
Source File http://localhost/eml/form.php
Row: 26 - elm.style.marginTop = (parseInt(y)-elm.clientHeight)/2 +"px"

Comment: I think you don't have div with id "mydiv" thats y its giving this error. check it once. if possible post your code in jsfiddle.

Comment: [read this code partial working... where is the error?](http://pastebin.com/Dn6JUXzz) I have div id="content" and not "mydiv"... this is obvious... thanks...

Comment: I read your code, you are getting width and height correctly but while subtracting values its giving NaN values, This can be eliminated by placing these lines  "      body_height = parseInt(body_height)
body_width = parseInt(body_width)  
div_height = parseInt(div_height)  
div_width = parseInt(div_width)    " after 18th line your code in that link.

Comment: user27722004, thanks, I solved in other manner... thanks for fixing my snippet :)

Comment: Welcome :).. Please close the question.

Answer (score 0):

so try this:

```
//this will center in vertical 
#form
{
   margin: auto;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried this trick too but without luck... the form becomes very height... the look becomes very bad... thanks.